# All the google accounts of all the phones waiting for C2DM push notifications must be registered on C2DM?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

i'm checking this link: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

It says that in order tu ouse C2DM, you need to ask for access, because it is a beta software. Here is the link to the signup form: http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/signup.html

OK, but.... wich account must ask for acces? the googleacount used in the server side? or all the millions of googleaccounts used on the millions of android phones that will receive notifications from the server?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your account which you use to deploy your app to android market. Use that email and register for C2DM. Once you register, and set up C2DM on the phone, the phone will get the registration id from google. The pre-requisites are that the phone should have a google account associated with it, and it should have android market installed. Also c2dm is supported only from 2.2 onwards.

Comment: then, the users of the phones, the clients, doesn't have to sign up here http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/signup.html ??? or yes?

Comment: No they dont need to signup anywhere

Answer (score 1):

You need a developer account to acces the C2DM, it is really recomendable to create another account for your app.

Comment: the googleaccount used to register on that link, is the google acount
that i must use on the server? or not? i didn't understand it

Answer (score 0):

> the googleaccount used to register on that link, is the google acount
>   that i must use on the server? or not? i didn't understand it

Yes, u should use the google account that u have registered through that link in your server application.